# How to see how many Twitter followers someone else has gained or lost over time?

Tags: twitter, analytics

I'd like to see if certain Twitter users are growing their followings or losing followers. Is there any application out there that can give me access to this information, preferably in graph form? (Klout, it appears, fails again to offer anything of much use here.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[TwitterCounter.com](http://twittercounter.com/) lets you see up to 6 months history of followers, following, and tweets. To see 6 months worth you have to tweet a message, but 3 months or less is available to see right away. Just sign in with twitter and search for a user and up it comes. Eg @spolsky:

[image]

Comment: As of this date, this service is 100% paid.

Answer (score 1):

[Twittercounter](http://twittercounter.com) gives you the graph not only for *followers* but also for *following* and *tweets*.